# RESOLVED: AWS CLI mv not recognizing exclude include arguments in bash script

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

Note: bash script now correct.

I am reorganizing my s3 file structure and want to essentially create 1000 subfolders because all my files are in one directory. For the example, I simplified this down to six files (these will be split into 3 subfolders).

In the terminal, the following command works perfectly for just the AAP subfolder.

```
aws s3 mv --recursive --dryrun --exclude="*" --include="opt_AAP_*.gz" s3://my-so/files/ s3://my-so/files/AAP/
```

And I get this:

```
(dryrun) move: s3://my-so/files/opt_AAP_1570545425.json.gz to s3://my-so/files/AAP/opt_AAP_1570545425.json.gz
(dryrun) move: s3://my-so/files/opt_AAP_1570546225.json.gz to s3://my-so/files/AAP/opt_AAP_1570546225.json.gz
```

When I create this in the following script, it seems to ignore the exclude and include arguments altogether. Even though I only have one of the 3 digit identifiers in the array, it wants to move all files. Other posts point to using quotes on the arguments, which I do, and others point to perhaps the way the array is using certain character sets, but I've not figure out how to see if that is the issue. This is puzzling as I don't want to have to do this manually a 1000 times for thousands of files. I could use python/boto3 and do copy/delete on individual files but I think this is an efficient means if I can figure out what is going on. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Bash script (on linux t3.micro AMI):**
**FIXED: CORRECT CODE BASED ON COMMENTS BELOW** - removed \ from quotes in the include and exclude arguments.

```
# declare an array variable
declare -a arr=("AAP")

# now loop through the above array
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
    command=(aws s3 mv  --recursive --dryrun --exclude="*"  --include="opt_"$i"_*.gz" s3://my-so/files/ s3://my-so/files/"$i"/ )

    echo  "${command[@]}"

    "${command[@]}" &

done
```

**And the incorrect dryrun:**

- AAP files should go to files/AAP/
- DFB files should go to files/DFB/
- TRO files should go to files/TRO/

```
(dryrun) move: s3://my-so/files/opt_AAP_1570545425.json.gz to s3://my-so/files/AAP/opt_AAP_1570545425.json.gz
(dryrun) move: s3://my-so/files/opt_AAP_1570546225.json.gz to s3://my-so/files/AAP/opt_AAP_1570546225.json.gz
(dryrun) move: s3://my-so/files/opt_DFB_1530546225.json.gz to s3://my-so/files/AAP/opt_DFB_1530546225.json.gz
(dryrun) move: s3://my-so/files/opt_DFB_1540546225.json.gz to s3://my-so/files/AAP/opt_DFB_1540546225.json.gz
(dryrun) move: s3://my-so/files/opt_TRO_1570546225.json.gz to s3://my-so/files/AAP/opt_TRO_1570546225.json.gz
(dryrun) move: s3://my-so/files/opt_TRO_1570546226.json.gz to s3://my-so/files/AAP/opt_TRO_1570546226.json.gz
```

Comment: dont you just have to say `$i` instead of `"$i"`

Comment: Don't escape the quotes when you create the `command` array. This will make it look wrong when you `echo` it, but that's normal; `echo` isn't showing what you think it is. Better yet, don't put the command in a variable at all, just execute it directly. See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: @GordonDavisson is correct. Removing the \ before the quotes fixed my code. Will read the link provided for additional insight. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should just change the code to `$1` from "$1"